# Item in the array did not validate: Select a valid choice. ["Acamedic" is not one of the available choices

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use CharField with choices using postgres ArrayField. here is my code;

```
BOOK_CATEGORY = (
    ("Academic", "Academic"),
    ("Science Fiction", "Science Fiction"),
    ("For Student", "For Student"),
    ("Others", "Others"),
)
```

```
class Book(models.Model):
    category = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=BOOK_CATEGORY), blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is the error I get when I try to post a value; `["Acamedic", "For Student", "Others"]`;
[image]

Comment: The key you're posting with is spelled differently than anything in `BOOK_CATEGORY`. 'Acamedic' is what you're posting with.

Comment: Can you use `models.TextField`? What is the data type of the DB field?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is from the syntax. I posted it as `["Academic", "For Student", "Others"]`. It rather supposed to be something like `Academic,For Student,Others`(Note: Without any space separating the different choices and no brackets and also no quotes)